# listview not listing on ICS

Tags: android, listview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to list json data in a listview. My application works on froyo and blue stacks emulator. But it's not listing anything in `ListView` on my phone and my friend's phone(both of them are ICS)

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstEcz);
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(
        this, nobList, R.layout.nob_eczane, 
        new String[] { "istasyon", "adres", "tel", "ilce" }, 
        new int[] { R.id.tvEczAd, R.id.tvEczAdres, R.id.tvEczTel, R.id.tvEczIlce }
);

list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

Comment: your internet must be ON in mobile

Comment: but i don't have any connection problem on my ics phone.both of my phones are connected to same wireless network.

Comment: check the list.size(); in your logcat..by putting this...Lod.v("log",""+list.size());

Comment: i've added Log.v("log",""+list.getCount()); and it returns 0. and i've add some logs to other operations.these are the log results. "In close() at SocketHttpClientConnection" "Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". i searched these and i think i can solve this with asynctask, but i don't have an idea how to use this yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class getInternet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
    {


           @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
           {
               super.onPreExecute();
               Utils.ShowProgressDialog();

           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0)
           {

            try 
            {

                      //your json parsing code...
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
           {
               super.onPostExecute(result);

            try
            {
                Utils.hideProgressDialog();
                list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
             Log.v("log", e.toString());
            }
           }

  }
```

Comment: great! thanks.. just one little thins. Utils cannot be resolved. i think it's your own class?

Comment: it is a class which contains the functions of show progress dialog and hide progress dialog..and please upvote so, other user can use this..